# Setting a variable to a specific value in a .csv file

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I am trying to retrieve the values in a .csv file (chimefrbcat1.csv) column #4 by nesting it inside a for-loop. However when I run the script, it simply outputs the numbers 2 to 599. I am trying to retrieve the values in column 4 from row 2 to row 599. My code is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {2..599..1}
do
  echo -n "$i"
  currentchimera=$(awk 'NR == $i {print $4}' chimefrbcat1.csv)
  echo "$currentchimera"
done
```

Comment: Please add sample input (with field separators, no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: The `for` loop is quite superfluous here. You can replace the entire script with `awk -F , 'NR >= 2 && NR <= 599 { print NR " " $4 }' chimefrbcat1.csv` (or well you need `print NR $4` to print the line number and the value without a space between them). Notice also the `-F ,` to specify comma-delimited.

Comment: A sample of the .csv file is:
name,previous_name,repeater_name,ra,ra_err,ra_notes,dec,dec_err,dec_notes
FRB20180725A,180725.J0613+67,-9999,93.42,0.04,-9999,67.1,0.2,-9999
FRB20180727A,180727.J1311+26,-9999,197.7,0.1,-9999,26.4,0.3,-9999
...


I am trying to get the variable currentchimera to contain the values 93.42 and then 197.7 and so on.
the full .csv file can be found here https://www.chime-frb.ca/catalog

Comment: @tripleee is there a way to make the output a variable because I will need the value for calculations later

Comment: `awk -F , 'NR >= 2 && NR <= 599 { print NR " " $4 }' chimefrbcat1.csv | while read -r lineno chimera; do echo "chimera on line $lineno is $chimera"; done`

Comment: @tripleee is it possible to modify it so that calculations can be made for each value in the variable ```chimera```. I need to be able to do calculations with the variable instead of listing all the values out. thanks for your help!

Comment: That's rather vague. Probably post a new question with your actual requirements and a [mre].